# How to Test Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mockery

I have an application that makes use of socialite, I want to create test for Github authentication, So I used Socialite Facade to mock call to the Socialite `driver` method, but when I run my test it tells me that I am trying to get value on null type.

Below is the test I have written

```
public function testGithubLogin()
{
    Socialite::shouldReceive('driver')
        ->with('github')
        ->once();
    $this->call('GET', '/github/authorize')->isRedirection();
}
```

Below is the implementation of the test

```
public function authorizeProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}
```

I understand why it might return such result because `Sociallite::driver($provider)` returns an instance of `Laravel\Socialite\Two\GithubProvider`, and considering that I am unable to instantiate this value it will be impossible to specify a return type. I need help to successfully test the controller. Thanks

Comment: I think you might want `Socialite::shouldReceive('driver->redirect')`.

Comment: @ceejayoz That does not work, it complains that it does not see the method `driver->redirect`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, both answers were great, but they have lots of codes that are not required, and I was able to infer my answer from them.

This is all I needed to do.

Firstly mock the Socialite User type

```
$abstractUser = Mockery::mock('Laravel\Socialite\Two\User')
```

Second, set the expected values for its method calls

```
$abstractUser
   ->shouldReceive('getId')
   ->andReturn(rand())
   ->shouldReceive('getName')
   ->andReturn(str_random(10))
   ->shouldReceive('getEmail')
   ->andReturn(str_random(10) . '@gmail.com')
   ->shouldReceive('getAvatar')
   ->andReturn('https://en.gravatar.com/userimage');
```

Thirdly, you need to mock the provider/user call

```
Socialite::shouldReceive('driver->user')->andReturn($abstractUser);
```

Then lastly you write your assertions

```
$this->visit('/auth/google/callback')
     ->seePageIs('/')
```

Comment: looks like a lot missing here

Comment: Not a lot, just the driver mock I forgot to add.

Comment: I don't understand this part `Socialite::shouldReceive('driver->user')->andReturn($abstractValidUser);`, is something missing? the `driver->user` part to be exactly

Comment: This became a complete mock example for me. Thanks.

Comment: @LTroya That part `driver->user` is a shortcut to mock a call to a chain of method. The reason for `driver->user` is because that is what is called when using Socialite. 
http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html

Answer (score 11):

```php
$provider = Mockery::mock('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Provider');
$provider->shouldReceive('redirect')->andReturn('Redirected');
$providerName = class_basename($provider);
//Call your model factory here
$socialAccount = factory('LearnCast\User')->create(['provider' => $providerName]);

$abstractUser = Mockery::mock('Laravel\Socialite\Two\User');
// Get the api user object here
$abstractUser->shouldReceive('getId') 
             ->andReturn($socialAccount->provider_user_id)
             ->shouldReceive('getEmail')
             ->andReturn(str_random(10).'@noemail.app')
             ->shouldReceive('getNickname')
             ->andReturn('Laztopaz')
             ->shouldReceive('getAvatar')
             ->andReturn('https://en.gravatar.com/userimage');

$provider = Mockery::mock('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Provider');
$provider->shouldReceive('user')->andReturn($abstractUser);

Socialite::shouldReceive('driver')->with('facebook')->andReturn($provider);

// After Oauth redirect back to the route
$this->visit('/auth/facebook/callback')
// See the page that the user login into
->seePageIs('/');
```

Note: `use` the socialite package at the top of your class

> use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

I had the same problem, but I was able to solve it using the technique above;   @ceejayoz. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

This may be harder to do, but I believe it makes for more readable tests. Hopefully you'll help me simplify what I'm about to describe.

My idea is to stub http requests. Considering facebook, there are two of them: 1) `/oauth/access_token` (to get access token), 2) `/me` (to get data about the user).

For that I temporarily attached `php` to [`mitmproxy`](https://mitmproxy.org/) to create `vcr` fixture:

1. Tell `php` to use http proxy (add the following lines to the `.env` file):

   ```
   HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:8080
   HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:8080
   ```
2. Tell `php` where proxy's certificate is: add `openssl.cafile = /etc/php/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem` to `php.ini`. Or `curl.cainfo`, for that matter.
3. Restart `php-fpm`.
4. Start `mitmproxy`.
5. <strike>Make your browser connect through `mitmproxy` as well.</strike>
6. Log in to the site you're developing using facebook (no TDD here).

   Press `z` in `mitmproxy` (`C` for `mitmproxy` < 0.18) to clear request (flow) list before redirecting to facebook if need be. Or alternatively, use `f` command (`l` for `mitmproxy` < 0.18) with `graph.facebook.com` to filter out extra requests.

   Do note, that for twitter you'll need `league/oauth1-client` 1.7 or newer. The one switched from `guzzle/guzzle` to `guzzlehttp/guzzle`. Or else you'll be unable to log in.
7. Copy data from `mimtproxy` to `tests/fixtures/facebook`. I used `yaml` format and here's what it looks like:

   ```
   -
       request:
           method: GET
           url: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=...&client_secret=...&code=...&redirect_uri=...
       response:
           status:
               http_version: '1.1'
               code: 200
               message: OK
           body: access_token=...&expires=...
   -
       request:
           method: GET
           url: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?access_token=...&appsecret_proof=...&fields=first_name,last_name,email,gender,verified
       response:
           status:
               http_version: '1.1'
               code: 200
               message: OK
           body: '{"first_name":"...","last_name":"...","email":"...","gender":"...","verified":true,"id":"..."}'
   ```

   For that you can use command `E` if you've got `mitmproxy` >= 0.18. Alternatively, use command `P`. It copies request/response to clipboard. If you want `mitmproxy` to save them right to file, you can run it with `DISPLAY= mitmproxy`.

   I see no way to use `php-vcr`'s recording facilities, since I'm not testing the whole workflow.

With that I was able to write the following tests (and yes, they are fine with all those values replaced by dots, feel free to copy as is).

**Do note** though, fixtures depend on `laravel/socialite`'s version. I had an issue with facebook. In version `2.0.16` `laravel/socialite` started doing [post requests](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/v2.0.16/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php#L75) to get access token. Also there's [api version](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/v2.0.16/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php#L22) in facebook urls.

These fixtures are for `2.0.14`. One way to deal with it is to have `laravel/socialite` dependency in `require-dev` section of `composer.json` file as well (with strict version specification) to ensure that `socialite` is of proper version in development environment (Hopefully, `composer` will ignore the one in `require-dev` section in production environment.) Considering you do `composer install --no-dev` in production environment.

`AuthController_HandleFacebookCallbackTest.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use VCR\VCR;

use App\User;

class AuthController_HandleFacebookCallbackTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        VCR::configure()->enableLibraryHooks(['stream_wrapper', 'curl'])
            ->enableRequestMatchers([
                'method',
                'url',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr facebook
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithCorrespondingName()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals('John Doe', User::first()->name);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr facebook
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithCorrespondingEmail()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals('john.doe@gmail.com', User::first()->email);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr facebook
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithCorrespondingFbId()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(123, User::first()->fb_id);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr facebook
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithFbData()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertNotEquals('', User::first()->fb_data);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr facebook
     */
    function testRedirectsToHomePage()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertRedirectedTo('/');
    }

    /**
     * @vcr facebook
     */
    function testAuthenticatesUser()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(User::first()->id, Auth::user()->id);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr facebook
     */
    function testDoesntCreateUserIfAlreadyExists()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'fb_id' => 123,
        ]);

        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(1, User::count());
    }

    function doCallbackRequest()
    {
        return $this->withSession([
            'state' => '...',
        ])->get('/auth/facebook/callback?' . http_build_query([
            'state' => '...',
        ]));
    }
}
```

`tests/fixtures/facebook`:

```
-
    request:
        method: GET
        url: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
    response:
        status:
            http_version: '1.1'
            code: 200
            message: OK
        body: access_token=...
-
    request:
        method: GET
        url: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me
    response:
        status:
            http_version: '1.1'
            code: 200
            message: OK
        body: '{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","email":"john.doe\u0040gmail.com","id":"123"}'
```

`AuthController_HandleTwitterCallbackTest.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use VCR\VCR;
use League\OAuth1\Client\Credentials\TemporaryCredentials;

use App\User;

class AuthController_HandleTwitterCallbackTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        VCR::configure()->enableLibraryHooks(['stream_wrapper', 'curl'])
            ->enableRequestMatchers([
                'method',
                'url',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr twitter
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithCorrespondingName()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals('joe', User::first()->name);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr twitter
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithCorrespondingTwId()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(123, User::first()->tw_id);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr twitter
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithTwData()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertNotEquals('', User::first()->tw_data);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr twitter
     */
    function testRedirectsToHomePage()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertRedirectedTo('/');
    }

    /**
     * @vcr twitter
     */
    function testAuthenticatesUser()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(User::first()->id, Auth::user()->id);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr twitter
     */
    function testDoesntCreateUserIfAlreadyExists()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'tw_id' => 123,
        ]);

        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(1, User::count());
    }

    function doCallbackRequest()
    {
        $temporaryCredentials = new TemporaryCredentials();
        $temporaryCredentials->setIdentifier('...');
        $temporaryCredentials->setSecret('...');
        return $this->withSession([
            'oauth.temp' => $temporaryCredentials,
        ])->get('/auth/twitter/callback?' . http_build_query([
            'oauth_token' => '...',
            'oauth_verifier' => '...',
        ]));
    }
}
```

`tests/fixtures/twitter`:

```
-
    request:
        method: POST
        url: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
    response:
        status:
            http_version: '1.1'
            code: 200
            message: OK
        body: oauth_token=...&oauth_token_secret=...
-
    request:
        method: GET
        url: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
    response:
        status:
            http_version: '1.1'
            code: 200
            message: OK
        body: '{"id_str":"123","name":"joe","screen_name":"joe","location":"","description":"","profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/456\/userpic.png"}'
```

`AuthController_HandleGoogleCallbackTest.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use VCR\VCR;

use App\User;

class AuthController_HandleGoogleCallbackTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        VCR::configure()->enableLibraryHooks(['stream_wrapper', 'curl'])
            ->enableRequestMatchers([
                'method',
                'url',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr google
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithCorrespondingName()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals('John Doe', User::first()->name);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr google
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithCorrespondingEmail()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals('john.doe@gmail.com', User::first()->email);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr google
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithCorrespondingGpId()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(123, User::first()->gp_id);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr google
     */
    function testCreatesUserWithGpData()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertNotEquals('', User::first()->gp_data);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr google
     */
    function testRedirectsToHomePage()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertRedirectedTo('/');
    }

    /**
     * @vcr google
     */
    function testAuthenticatesUser()
    {
        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(User::first()->id, Auth::user()->id);
    }

    /**
     * @vcr google
     */
    function testDoesntCreateUserIfAlreadyExists()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'gp_id' => 123,
        ]);

        $this->doCallbackRequest();

        $this->assertEquals(1, User::count());
    }

    function doCallbackRequest()
    {
        return $this->withSession([
            'state' => '...',
        ])->get('/auth/google/callback?' . http_build_query([
            'state' => '...',
        ]));
    }
}
```

`tests/fixtures/google`:

```
-
    request:
        method: POST
        url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
    response:
        status:
            http_version: '1.1'
            code: 200
            message: OK
        body: access_token=...
-
    request:
        method: GET
        url: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
    response:
        status:
            http_version: '1.1'
            code: 200
            message: OK
        body: '{"emails":[{"value":"john.doe@gmail.com"}],"id":"123","displayName":"John Doe","image":{"url":"https://googleusercontent.com/photo.jpg"}}'
```

Note. Make sure you have `php-vcr/phpunit-testlistener-vcr` required, and that you have the following line in your `phpunit.xml`:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class="PHPUnit_Util_Log_VCR" file="vendor/php-vcr/phpunit-testlistener-vcr/PHPUnit/Util/Log/VCR.php"/>
</listeners>
```

There also was an issue with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` not being set, when running tests. I'm talking about `config/services.php` file here, namely about redirect url. I handled it like so:

```
 <?php

$app = include dirname(__FILE__) . '/app.php';

return [
    ...
    'facebook' => [
        ...
        'redirect' => (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : $app['url']) . '/auth/facebook/callback',
    ],
];
```

Not particularly beautiful, but I failed to find a better way. I was going to use `config('app.url')` there, but it doesn't work in config files.

**UPD** You can get rid of `setUpBeforeClass` part by removing this method, running tests, and updating request part of fixtures with what vcr records. Actually, the whole thing might be done with `vcr` alone (no `mitmproxy`).

Comment: if anything, this is a real interesting idea using php-vcr.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually created Fake classes that return a dummy user data because I'm interested in testing my logic, not whether Socialite, nor the vendor work properly.

```php
// This is the fake class that extends the original SocialiteManager
class SocialiteManager extends SocialiteSocialiteManager
{
    protected function createFacebookDriver()
    {
        return $this->buildProvider(
            FacebookProvider::class, // This class is a fake that returns dummy user in facebook's format
            $this->app->make('config')['services.facebook']
        );
    }

    protected function createGoogleDriver()
    {
        return $this->buildProvider(
            GoogleProvider::class, // This is a fake class that ereturns dummy user in google's format
            $this->app->make('config')['services.google']
        );
    }
}
```

And here is how one of the Fake providers look like:

```php
class FacebookProvider extends SocialiteFacebookProvider
{
    protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
        return [
            'id' => '123123123',
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'avatar' => 'image.jpg',
        ];
    }
}
```

And of course in the test class, I replace the original SocialiteManager with my version:

```php
public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->app->singleton(Factory::class, function ($app) {
            return new SocialiteManager($app);
        });
    }
```

This works pretty fine to me. No need to mock anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily swap Socialite implementation, e.g. using anonymous classes. Basic implementation:

```
Socialite::swap(new class implements \Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory
{
    public function driver($driver = null)
    {
        return new class implements \Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Provider
        {
            public function redirect()
            {
                return new \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse('/');
            }

            public function user(): \Laravel\Socialite\Two\User
            {
                $user = new \Laravel\Socialite\Two\User();
                $user->name = 'John Doe';
                $user->email = 'john.doe@example.com';

                return $user;
            }

            public function stateless(): self // optional method
            {
                return $this;
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Of course, you can extract it into a separate method or even classes for readability reasons. Here, I just share the concept that can be improved (e.g. you can pass a callback to Provider implementation constructor that you can call in user() method and return value from this closure; this way you can return any value from user() method).

This is how you test may look like:

```
Socialite::swap(/* ... */);

$response = $this->get('/auth/google/callback');

$response->assertRedirect();
$this->assertDatabaseHas(\App\Models\User::class, [
    'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use `stateless()` in Laravel-Socialite which Laravel roled as pure API without a frontend.

You may add a `stateless` mock provider for your callback test.

```php
$mock_provider->shouldReceive('stateless')->andReturn($mock_provider);
```

---

Your callback code may look like following

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/SocialTokensController.php**

```php
public function callback (String $type, Request $request) {
    $credentials = Socialite::driver($type)->stateless()->user();
    ...
}
```

**tests/Feature/Auth/SocialTokens/CallbackTest.php**

```php
protected function boot_mocker($type, $social_account_id) {

    $mock_user = Mockery::mock('Laravel\Socialite\Two\User');
    $mock_user
        ->shouldReceive('getId')
        ->andReturn($social_account_id);

    $mock_provider = Mockery::mock('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Provider');
    $mock_provider
        ->shouldReceive('user')
        ->andReturn($mock_user);
    $mock_provider
        ->shouldReceive('stateless')
        ->andReturn($mock_provider);

    Socialite::shouldReceive('driver')
        ->with($type)
        ->andReturn($mock_provider)
        ->once();
}

protected function new_user_login_via_social_oauth ($type) {

    $social_key = 'social->' . $type;
    $social_account_id = Str::random(10);

    $this->assertDatabaseMissing('users', [
        $social_key => $social_account_id,
    ]);

    $this->boot_mocker($type, $social_account_id);

    $response = $this->post(
        route('auth.social.tokens.callback', ['type' => $type])
    );

    $response->assertStatus(302);
    $response->assertRedirect('/profile');
        
    $token_from_request_cookie = $response->headers->getCookies()[0]->getValue();
    $auth_response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token_from_request_cookie
        ])
        ->get(route('auth.user.show'));

    $auth_response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Here is [a full example](https://github.com/DengSihan/laravel-nuxt3-api) which is 100% test coverage