# InvalidStateException when testing mocked Socialite login via Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, mockery, laravel-dusk

I'm using Socialite in a Laravel application to allow users to connect via Github.

My login controller contains the following two methods:

```php
    /**
     * GET /login/github
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * GET /login/github/callback
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
    {
        $githubUser = Socialite::driver('github')->user();

        // Actual login procedures go here; redacted for brevity

        return redirect('/'); 
    }
```

When I manually test these methods in the browser, they work as expected. I visit `/login/github` where I'm redirected to Github to authenticate, then I'm sent back to `/login/github/callback?state=somelongrandomkey` which then redirects me home (`/`).

I'm also attempting to test these methods via Laravel Dusk, mocking Socialite.

My Dusk test method looks like this:

```php
    public function testReceivesGithubRequestAndCreatesNewUser()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {

            $user = factory('App\Models\User')->create([
                'github_token' => 'foobar',
                'github_username' => 'foobar'
            ]);

            # Mock 1 - A Socialite user
            $abstractUser = Mockery::mock('Laravel\Socialite\Two\User');

            # Mock 2 - Socialite's Github provider
            $provider = Mockery::mock('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Provider');
            $provider->shouldReceive('user')
                ->andReturn($abstractUser);

            # Mock 3 - Socialite
            Socialite::shouldReceive('driver')
                ->with('github')
                ->andReturn($provider);

            $browser->visit('/login/github/callback')->assertPathIs('/');
        });
```

When I run this test, the visit to `/login/github/callback` fails with an `InvalidStateException`.

From the log:

```php
dusk.local.ERROR: {"exception":"[object] (Laravel\\Socialite\\Two\\InvalidStateException(code: 0):  at /redacted/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php:210)
[stacktrace]
#0 /redacted/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php(84): Laravel\\Socialite\\Two\\AbstractProvider->user()
[...etc...]
```

When I [trace where the error is coming from in AbstractProvider](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/4.0/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php#L242)
I see it's attempting to compare `state` from the session with `state` from the query string:

```php
protected function hasInvalidState()
    {
        if ($this->isStateless()) {
            return false;
        }
        $state = $this->request->session()->pull('state');
        return ! (strlen($state) > 0 && $this->request->input('state') === $state);
    }
```

In my Dusk test, when `/login/github/callback` is visited, there is no state on the query string, so it's logical that it's failing.

I feel I'm missing some key component in setting up the mocks that provides that state, but I'm not sure what.

My test is built using these two examples for reference:

- [How to Test Laravel Socialite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37220779/59479)
- [How I write integration tests for Laravel Socialite powered apps](https://stefanzweifel.io/posts/how-i-write-integration-tests-for-laravel-socialite-powered-apps/)

Comment: There's a fundamental difference between Dusk tests and the examples you're mentioning: Dusk opens the website in an actual browser and so the test and your application run in separate processes. That's why mocking doesn't work in Dusk tests. The idea behind such an integration test is that you simulate a real user, without mocking or any other "shortcuts". In your case, that would mean logging in with a real GitHub account.

Comment: "the test and your application run in separate processes" Ok - that makes sense, and explains why my mocks weren't working as expected. I also understand now why my integration test needs a different approach. You should make this comment an answer on this thread, as I believe you're spot on.

Comment: @sbuck did you manage to solve it? What approach are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental difference between Dusk tests and the examples you're mentioning: Dusk opens the website in an actual browser and so the test and your application run in separate processes. That's why mocking doesn't work in Dusk tests.

The idea behind such an integration test is that you simulate a real user, without mocking or any other "shortcuts". In your case, that would mean logging in with a real GitHub account.